# Deploying helloworld to app engine flexible with go111 fails

Tags: go, app-engine-flexible

I'm attempting to deploy the helloworld app (source code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine_flexible/helloworld)) to app engine flexible. When I deploy this without any changes to the code, everything works fine. But I want to use go1.11, so I changed the app.yaml to say

```
runtime: go111    # changed from runtime: go
```

and I get the error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [go111].  Please correct the errors and try again.
```

This is not a very helpful error message and googling hasn't helped so far as well. What can I do to debug/fix this issue?

Comment: Have you initialized the module in the directory before changing the version to 1.11? Try `go mod init hello_world` in the app and try it again. Maybe it will solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **App Engine Documentation Go Flexible Environment**
>
> [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#general)
>
> runtime: go
>
> This setting is required. It is the name of the App
>   Engine language runtime used by this application. To specify Go, use
>   go, and it will default to the latest supported Go version;
>   alternatively, specify one of the following supported release
>   versions: go1.10, go1.9, or go1.8.

---

> I want to use go1.11, so I changed the app.yaml to say runtime: go111
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of
>   the requirements for a runtime of type [go111].  Please correct the
>   errors and try again.

Think about it for a moment. Is runtime of type `go111` `go1.11` or `go11.1`?

---

Read the error message.

> `ERROR: runtime of type [go111]`.

Read the documentation.

> specify one of the following supported release versions: go1.10

Which would make Go 1.11 `go1.11`.

You used `go111` and got

```
ERROR: runtime of type [go111].
```

What happens if you follow the instructions in the documentation and use `go1.11` for Go 1.11?

Comment: Thanks - that worked! I originally followed the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/config/appref - which  says runtime: go111. I realise now that that is for the standard app engine. Would've been nice if they stuck to the same naming convention for standard and flex.

Comment: This got me as well. I was reading their docs and thought it strange.